# Showing one video for a product out of several videos in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video

In my rails app, I have a product category. Each product can have multiple videos(from Youtube or vimeo).

I have generated a model and migration with following columns

```
:title, :description, :video_link, :product_id
```

I would like to show only one video on the product display page as a main or primary video and the rest videos on "details on product" page.

/product.rb

```
has_many :video_links, dependent: :destroy
```

/video_link.rb

```
 belongs_to :product
```

So my question is, how should I approach to mark one video to display on the product front page (view) and the rest videos for details page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how should I approach to mark one video to display on the product front page (view) and the rest videos for details page?

That depends on what you want a "front page video" to mean.

- An editorial decision: add a boolean column for 'featured' or 'front page', and let the editorial decision makers flip that flag at will. You could either have other code to make it unique, or add a date and take the latest of the featured videos.
- The hottest video: keep track of views or votes per video, and display the latest one with the maximum view/vote count on the front page.
- The latest video: add an `updated_at` column and pick the video with the largest value.
- etc.

In other words it looks like at this stage this is a design rather than a coding issue.

Comment: Thanks Mori. The first one of you comments. I want that a manufacture/admin can make a decision to choose which one will be the primary one. My question is how to make one video primary out of many?

Comment: @SubratRout, we do it by taking the most recently updated of the flagged records. E.g. `Product.video_links.where(featured: true).order(:updated_at).last`. So in your case you'd add both columns `featured` and `updated_at`. Alternatively, at the time you flip on `featured` for one record you can also flip it off for all other records.

Answer (score 1):

You can have another column that is something like "main_video" on the "video_links" table that is a boolean and just display that one whenever you need to grab just one.

Comment: Thanks. My question is if a manufacturer or admin upload a video_link to a product then how can he/she choose to display only one as primary. I mean where and how do I put that constraint?